# How to create a cryptocurrency based woocommerce multi-vendor store?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a cryptocurrency multi-vendor store based on WooCommerce.

I have plugins from https://www.dashed-slug.net that allow to deposit, withdraw, move coins within accounts and etc. & I also have "YITH WOOCOMMERCE MULTI VENDOR Premium" plugin (it also has a free version) - https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-vendors/.

Everything would seem to be working (sellers get their cryptocurrency addresses, can move funds within other wallets & etc). However, the problem appears when let's say a seller posts an item for sale. Buyer comes and pays with the cryptocurrency. Thing is that cryptocurrency somwhy goes to the Administrator account, not the Vendor (Seller) account and stays there. Or for example if I try to buy "Seller's" item with the Administrator account - it tells "You cannot send funds to yourself".

Dashed-slug creator told me that there should be some way to do it and referred me to https://wallets-phpdoc.dashed-slug.net/classes/Dashed_Slug_Wallets_PHP_API.html#method_api_move_action

However, my WordPress / PHP / WooCommerce knowledge is too weak.

Can anyone help me with this?